# Django: combine an object and a QuerySet?

Tags: django

I want to combine an object and a QuerySet in Django.

My objects are as follows:

```
class Book(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=400)
    library_id = models.FloatField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True, unique=True)
    copy_id = models.FloatField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)
```

My query is as follows (I'm looking up a book by ID, then finding all books that are copies, i.e. share a `copy_id` with the `library_id` of this book:

```
    primary_book = Book.objects.get(id=book_id)
    book_copies = Book.objects.filter(copy_id=primary_book.library_id)
    if book_copies:
        books = primary_book | book_copies
    else:
        books = primary_book
```

Perhaps there's a better way to run the query? But at the moment I'm a bit stuck, because this is producing `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for |: 'Book' and 'QuerySet'`.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Edit] If you don't require a queryset:

```
books = [primary_book] + list(book_copies)
```

You could try using this if you do need a qs:

```
primary_books = Book.objects.filter(id=book_id)
book_copies = Book.objects.filter(copy_id=primary_books[0].library_id)
if book_copies:
    books = primary_books | book_copies
else:
    books = primary_books[0]
```

Or if you wanted to redo your model since it looks like your `copy_id` to `library_id` is a many to one relationship:

**models.py**

```
class Book(models.Model):
    library_id = models.FloatField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True, unique=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=400)
    primary_book = models.ForeignKeyField('self', to_field='library_id', related_name='book_copies', null=True, blank=True)
```

**views.py**

```
from django.db.models import Q
books = Book.objects.filter(Q(id=book_id)|Q(primary_book__id=book_id))
```

Comment: still, in second example you will need to fetch primary_book first - so no gain here at all. if you want to be exact, code should be: books = [primary_book] + list(book_copies) [order sometimes does matter] :)